# Error with apostrophe when using tagsoup

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, html-parsing, tag-soup

I am attempting to grab the description of a website in a node.js web application. It seems to be working perfectly, however node.js appears to be having issues with the NCR characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference). The code I have for the link grabber is shown below

```
getInfo:(url) ->
  errorMessage = 'Invalid Link'

  request(url, (error, response, body)->
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
      handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler((err, dom) ->
        if (err)
          res(error: errorMessage)
        else
          imgs = select(dom, 'img')
          titletags = select(dom,'title')
          descripTags = select(dom,'meta')
          filteredTags = _.filter(descripTags,(tag) -> tag.attribs.name? && tag.attribs.name == 'description')

          uri = response.request.uri.href

          mapFunc =(imgSrc) ->
            pattern = /^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)/
            img = imgSrc.attribs.src
            if (!pattern.test(img)) then uri.substring(0,uri.length-1) + img else img

          res(
            images: _.filter(_.map(imgs,mapFunc),(img)-> (img != '')) || []
            title: titletags[0].children[0].raw || ''
            description: if filteredTags.length != 0 then filteredTags[0].attribs.content || '' else ''
          )
      )
      parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler)
      parser.parseComplete(body)
    else
      res(error: errorMessage)
  )
```

As an example, if I put in the following URL for to grab info form (http://www.zdnet.com), the description will be `ZDNet&#039;s breaking news, analysis, and research keeps business technology professionals in touch with the latest IT trends, issues and events.`. The apostrophe is the issue (being represented as `&#039;`)

My question is, why aren't any of the libraries properly parsing the valid HTML NCR's and converting them to the string equivalent, and if there isn't a way to fix this, is it just safe to replace all occurrences of NCR's using some other library?

The libraries I am using are described below

```
request = require 'request'
htmlparser = require 'htmlparser'
select = require('soupselect').select
_ = require 'underscore'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the https://github.com/minchenkov/node-html-encoder library to decode the strings, worked fine (not sure why the node.js standard libraries don't html decode strings by default)